# get result of non-existent dates too

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySql table containing events having a DATETIME timestamp. I want to count each day's events. On some days, e.g. on Sundays, events are missing. The result should contain these days too with a count of zero.

My query is the following:

```
SELECT 

COUNT(1) AS mycount,
DATE_FORMAT(DATE(evaluations.timestamp),"%a, %d.%m.%Y") AS date
FROM Events 
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
ORDER BY DATE(timestamp) DESC
```

Can I modify the query without using a helper table containing all dates?
A single query (no procedere, no function) would be fine.

Comment: The simplest solution is to have a `Calendar` table for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The query would somehow look like this if you don't have any `calendar` table:

```
SELECT 
 dateTable.day,
 COALESCE(t.mycount,0) AS cnt
FROM 
(
SELECT ADDDATE((SELECT MIN(DATE(timestamp)) FROM Events), INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY) AS DAY
FROM (
SELECT a.a
FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
) a
JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) r1
WHERE 
@i < DATEDIFF((SELECT MAX(DATE(timestamp)) FROM Events), (SELECT MIN(DATE(timestamp)) FROM Events))
) AS dateTable
LEFT JOIN 
(
        SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS mycount,
        DATE_FORMAT(DATE(evaluations.timestamp),"%a, %d.%m.%Y") AS date
        FROM Events 
        GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
        ORDER BY DATE(timestamp) DESC
) AS t
ON dateTable.day = t.date
ORDER BY dateTable.day DESC;
```

**Note:**

If you think you will need this kind of query too often then you can create a table where all the dates would reside.  <sub>Newer dates can be added through `mysql event` periodically</sub> .

Then the work is simple. Just need to make a `LEFT JOIN` between the `calendar` table and the result of your query.

Comment: It would be nice it there was a builtin calendar table.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no such feature. You have to implement it.